Are there any other Git files I need to copy, besides Gitconfig?
Yesterday something deleting my .gitconfig file from my $USER folder on my Windows 11 machine. I'm going to try and recover it from an old PC I have, but while I'm at it I'm wondering if there's other Git related files, not in repositories, which I should also make a copy of?

Maybe consider .git-credentials too? (also in your user home folder, alongside .gitconfig)

I suppose they are only relevant if you use them, but you probably want everything in $GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR.

.gitignore is worth copying over as it specifies intentionally untracked files to ignore.

.gitignore is part of the repo.

There is also a global .gitignore

The fact that you can have both per-repo .gitignores as well as a global one (ignoring e.g. temporary files created by your editor of choice) may (and did already) cause confusion. You can [edit] and clarify your answer.

I'll get the global .gitignore, too.
